# Darn and d—n, are they connected?

Tags: etymology, minced-oaths

I am curious about the word *darn* and its use as a verb meaning to mend knitted clothing and as a minced oath substituting for *damn.*

Did *darn* become a minced oath simply because it sounds like *damn* and was well-known?  Or is there some connection between the meaning of fixing a worn item and condemning something?

[*Note* The title is bowdlerised as is customary. I'm not asking about the bowdlerisation of *damn.*]

Comment: Hello, nuggerhead. The Online Etymology Dictionary is often used to check on word origins. While its accuracy isn't guaranteed, it's often considered pretty reliable.

Comment: The earliest record of the word is in 1781, in the Pennsylvania Journal of 20th of June --  *In New England prophane swearing..is so far from polite as to be criminal, and many..use..substitutions such as darn it, for d—n it.* obviously, the author saw no connection between damning an item and darning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Darn* is most likely a minced oath (in sound or look) to *damn*. In the Oxford English Dictionary, that sense ("[darn, adv. and adj.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47329)" or "[darned, adv. and adj.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47332)2") is completely separate from the mending sense ("[darn, v.1](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47327)" or "[darned, adj.1](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47331)"). Their etymologies are held as separate too. For dictionaries, they are separate words. While it's always possible there was some punning between the two meanings, I haven't found evidence of it yet.

As for the word being a *minced* oath, it's worth considering the sounds and form of *darn* compared to *damn*. For the sounds, the two start similarly (/dɑ/, /da/, /dæ/) but then have different final consonants (/rn/, /m/). In terms of form, if you consider all the similar letter shapes (the [minims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(palaeography)) or short vertical strokes), the letters [rn] are close to the letter [m] in the number of minims and the bridges between them. So *darn* is close to *damn* and even closer to the variant spelling *dam*. Thus *darn* is as much a minced oath to eye as to ear.

Comment: Yes, rn looks like m, but damn ends mn

Comment: Can non-subscribers access OED from a link?

Comment: @nuggethead Yes. It's not an exact match for *damn*, but it's close. Also, *damn* can also be spelled *dam* ("1867   J. W. De Forest Miss Ravenel's Conversion xxi. 295   He is, by Jove! a **dam** incur-dam-able darn coward." "1918   W. J. Locke Rough Road xviii   It's all **dam** funny!")

Comment: Probably Southern US, and compares with  *Shut the front door*, also Southern, where the R is added.